# How to test a search view page with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

```
# encoding: utf-8
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = User.search(params[:search])
    @users = @search.paginate :per_page => 20, :page => params[:page]
  end

end


<h2>User search</h2>
<%= form_for @search, :url => users_path, :html => { :method => :get } do |f| %>
#some form elements
<% end %>

<% @users.each do |user| %> 
# show user info
<% end %>
```

Now how to test view with rspec 2?

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'spec_helper'

describe "users/index.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do

    ####@user = stub_model(User)
            ######User.stub!(:search).and_return(@post)
      How to mock? If not mock(or stubed), it will got a nil error when rspec test.


  end

  it "renders a list of users" do
    render

    rendered.should contain("User search")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it "renders a list of users" do
  assign(:search, stub_model(???)) # see note
  assign(:users, [stub_model(User)]
  render
  rendered.should contain("User search")
end
```

`assign` allows the spec to refer to the instance variables that would be expected in a normal view. `@users` needs to be an array, thus the brackets.

Note: replace the question marks with whatever type of object gets returned from `User.search`.

**EDIT**

Well this is trickier than it appears at first blush. I could not find an easy way to mock up an object that can respond to the necessary messages to get this spec to pass. The quick and dirty way is to just use a real object:

```
it "renders a list of users" do
  assign(:search, User.search)
  assign(:users, [stub_model(User)]
  render
  rendered.should contain("User search")
end
```

The disadvantage is that this needs a database connection to work. We could hack up our own helper object:

```
class MetaSearchTestHelper
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  attr_accessor :model_name
  def initialize(options={})
    @model_name = options[:model_name] || nil
  end
  def singular
    @model_name ? @model_name.downcase : nil
  end
  def persisted?
    false
  end
end

it "renders a list of users" do
  assign(:search, MetaSearchTestHelper.new(:model_name=>"User")
  assign(:users, [stub_model(User)]
  render
  rendered.should contain("User search")
end
```

Which works for this spec -- but will it work for others?

Comment: Very thanks for your answer.
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > User.search.class
MetaSearch::Searches::User < MetaSearch::Builder

How to replace?

Comment: Failure/Error: assign(:search, stub_model(MetaSearch::Searches::User)) # see note
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: I added some other suggestions.

Comment: This won't work anymore since ActiveModel::Naming.model_name_from_record_or_class calls #class on the MetaSearchTestHelper object.